# Basic code to make a module themable

Tags: theming

I almost titled the question "Hello world of theming a module", as that quite well describes what I'm looking for. I feel maybe it's to much "slang" though. There's probably a lot of people out there in this situation. I know a lot about programming, but very little about (Drupal) theming.

So, for a trivial "Hello world" module like:

```
function _modules_page_callback($data) {
  return '<span class="module-functionality">' . $data . '</span>';
}
```

What does the equally trivial version look like, that moves the HTML into the theme-layer?

Comment: Can you tag your post with 6 or 7? The theme layers are slightly different between the two versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first let Drupal's theme system know about your "theme" functions. You just create a function called `mymodule_theme` and that should return an array with your theme functions defined. See [hook_theme](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) for more details.

Example:

```
function mymodule_theme() {
  return array(
    'funstuff_output' => array(
      'variables' => array('node' => NULL),
    ),
  );
}
```

Now the 'funstuff_output' function does not exist... so create it!

```
function theme_funstuff_output($variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  $output = '<h1>' . $node->title . ' is fun stuff</h1>';
  return $output;
}
```

Now you can call taht theme function anywhere like so: `print theme('funstuff_output', array('node' => $node));`

In Drupal 6, I think variables is called arguments and there are some other differences. But that's the basics.

Comment: Cool, now we got both 6 and 7 answers. :) I'll accept yours as right, since that's what most people are likely interested in.

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 6, I will attempt to answer this myself, since I've continued my research since I asked the question. Our module below is called something original, "foo".

foo.module:

```
function foo_theme() {
  return array(
    'foo_useful_output' => array(
      'arguments' => array('data' => NULL),
      'file' => drupal_get_path('module', 'foo') . '/foo.theme.inc',
    ),
  );
}

function _modules_page_callback($data) {
  return theme('foo_useful_output', $data);
}
```

foo.theme.inc

```
function theme_foo_useful_output($data) {
  return '<span class="module-functionality">' . $data . '</span>';
}
```